# Nothing runs in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, notepad++

I'm new at programming. I've done the HTML, CSS, website build and JAVASCRIPT courses on Codecademy. I've done some of the Eloquent Javascript and got a little lost in the sauce around chapter 5. I saw someone advise on here to take the JavascriptIsSexy route which I've been doing. I downloaded Notepad++ and have started going through "Beginning Javascript" book that is used in that "study guide". My problem is I cannot get anything, and I mean anything to run in a browser. IE, Firefox or Chrome. Even the simplest of things produce no output. The page loads either blank, or shows the first line of HTML and no more. Any blocks, functions and the like never run. White page. 1 or no lines. I've looked around for anyone having similar issues and haven't found it. Which makes me pretty sure I'm the problem here. I'd offer samples of code, but anything you can write in 60 would suffice as a good example. I am saving the files in a designated folder with the correct file types (.html or .js), closing all tags, etc.

Not exactly sure how to continue. I can't keep "practicing" if i cant get anything to run. I've tried using the RUN button in Notepad++ and selecting a browser. I've also tried opening a browser, choosing OPEN and selecting one of the files. I've even directly copied and pasted code right out of the book and tried to run it that way to make sure it isn't just a bug on my part. Same result. 
I also tried writing and playing with codes in the "console" of IE and Chrome, but I can't get either of them to respond as I have no idea how to use them.

If this is a really dumb question or I haven't given you enough info to try and help me out, I apologize. I would appreciate any help you guys could throw out there.

Thanks.

First of all, you guys are awesome. I thought I'd be waiting for a couple days for some help. Seriously, that's cool. Here's a bit of code, one of the first examples the book has you run in a browser.

```
 <html>

  <body bgColor = "WHITE">

    <p>Paragraph 1</p> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("First Script Block"); 
    </script7>

    <p>Paragraph 2</p>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      document.bgColor ="RED"; 
      alert("Second Script Block");
    </script7>  

    <p>Paragraph 3</p>

  </body> 
 </html>
```

Like I said. Very simple... I get nothing. Thanks again for the quick responses. You guys rock.

Comment: I'ld suggest you add one of the simple examples that is not running for you that way people can attempt to duplicate what you are seeing and offer advice to that specific issue.

Comment: Post some of your code? Have you tried using plunkr to test you code out?  http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Please post an example of some code that isn't running for you, and the steps you are taking to try to run it. If we know what isn't working, it will be easier for us to suggest how to fix it!

Comment: Question will likely get closed....don't be discouraged... add some code attempts and shorten up the narrative..but include steps taken along with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a dumb question at all. This is one of the most common things to try and get used to when you're starting out. So I'll ask you a question because this is the most common thing that newcomers forget - did you load all you files in to your index.html (or whatever your html file is name) file? If you're not sure, go to your website or page, and view source. Do a search for '.css'. If you can't find anything, you haven't loaded any stylesheets. Next do a search for 'script'. If you can't find that, you didn't include any javascript files. Is your site live? You need to FTP to it and upload the files to the server also. Here's a resource for importing your stylesheets and scripts into the DOM. http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/ If you need help with FTP, let me know, I'd be glad to help, as I wish someone would have helped me when I was starting out.

Comment: First of all, you guys are awesome. I thought I'd be waiting for a couple days for some help. Seriously, that's cool.               Here's a bit of code, one of the first examples the book has you run in a browser.      <!DOCTYPYE html>
<html>

<body bgColor = "WHITE">
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("First Script Block");
</script7>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.bgColor ="RED";
 alert("Second Script Block");
</script7>

<p>Paragraph 3</p>


</body>

</html>                             Like I said. Very simple... I get nothing.

Comment: Wow. That's indecipherable. Sorry guys. It won't let me "return" to line it out properly for you.

Comment: Okay, first of all, "bgColor" is very outdated. If you're going to use inline styling (that is, styling that's included in the DOM, or HTML file) you should be using a "style" tag, e.g. <style>/* Some CSS*/</style>. Also, you don't want to assign a background color to your document, nor do you want to use javascript (or any script) to assign styles, all of those things should be done with CSS. I'll admit it's a little tough to decipher the whole issue, since all I have is a code snippet here. Your closing script tag has an unwanted 7, and that's all the characters I have left/

Comment: Yeah. Some of the differences I've seen between the online courses and this book. The  7 in </script7> and the bgColor instead of style="background-color: red". I just figured I didn't know all the different sytax. Maybe I just need a different book.

Answer (score 2):

Open a new file in Notepad++ and add:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    alert('This Should be a Popup Alert')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Save as test.html, make sure to save as "All Files".

Right click on the file, and open with any browser and should run in the browser just fine.  Now just adapt the javascript you want to play with.

Comment: @J.Dederick If this has helped you out and you feel that it's answered your question please mark this as your answer by clicking the tick next to the code I've added

Comment: Hey man. I appreciate the help. I did try that and still got nothing. White page, no popup. I'll keep trying. Thanks again.

Comment: Your code above has </script7> closing.. change that to </script>

Comment: Also, if the code I added doesn't work try a different editor.  I'm using Sublime Text 2 and that code runs fine on Safari.  I'm not familiar with Notepad++, so not sure if there might be a problem with settings or something along those lines

Comment: Have you disabled javascript in your browser @J.Dederick?

Comment: Yeah. Was just talking about that with dSummer.1289. It worked. Thanks alot man. I gotta get a different book. Apparently, it's using old terms. Ya get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using console.log() to produce output, you won't see it in the browser's window that normally displays HTML. You need to look at the console. On Chrome it can be reached via the menu at View > Developer > Developer Tools.

Comment: Wasn't using console.log(), but that's good to know anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste a code snippet in one of your index.html pages, you should try to learn and use xammp.

1. Install xammp
2. Once installed click the button "Start" on Apache
3. Move the project / website your doing into the following directory, make a folder name for it e.g. TestOne  **C:\xampp\htdocs**
4. open Google Chrome or IE and put the following in the URL

localhost/TestOne/index.html

or whatever your index file of the website your making index.php etc..

Answer (score -1):

You may need to run it on a server. You can make a local sever with tomcat. I hope this commit helps. You can always use a online website to emulate running it on your machine.

thanks,
      adbadb25

Comment: Thanks so much Michael for clarifying. I have the same problem. That was just a guess from my programming class.

Answer (score -1):

When you are first learning how to code, I would start with a basic html format. Html,head, closing head,body, closing body,closing html. Inside the body tags, start with something simple. Opening and closing paragraphs tags. "Hello World".